# Android VLC player can not play audio file with query string

Tags: android, .htaccess, ubuntu, streaming, token

I have audio files in my ubuntu server and .htaccess files for token control. I can download audio files when i try but vlc can not play them. Any suggestions

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, if you provide your code attempts so far then the community are going to be much more inclined to help that than 'give me code' without evidence of effort. That way they can help many more people.

Comment: i googled it and find out vlc cannot open urls with querystring then, i changed my url www.url.com/file.mp3?token=12345 to www.url.com/token/12345/file.mp3 and .htaccess to 
RewriteCond 
%{REQUEST_URI} !^/token/12345/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/token/12345/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
then everthing works fine